# How to add a new zone in firewalld without blocking `port=80/tcp` in `zone=public` in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: firewalld, firewall-cmd, firewalld-zone

I'm not too familiar with firewalld, but I thought I'd try it out on Ubuntu20.04.  The problem I'm having is that `port=80/tcp` in `zone=public` gets blocked every time I try to add a new zone.

So my question is: how do I add a new zone without it blocking `port=80/tcp` in `zone=public`?

I describe what I did below.

(**edit** - I explain at end of this questions that these same actions are successful in ubuntu 18.04 and centos 8, but fail in ubuntu 20.04)

First, I install a clean instance of Ubuntu 20.04 on a VPS.  Then I run these commands as root user from terminal:

```
# make sure ufw is not used
systemctl stop ufw && systemctl disable ufw;

# install a webserver so I can test port 80 will give me a web page
apt-get install -y apache2;

# install firewalld and configure
apt-get install -y firewalld;
systemctl start firewalld;
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp;
firewall-cmd --reload;
```

Now when I go to my server's ip address with a web browser, I can see the default apache web page.

Next, here is where things get unusual.  I'll list my experiments in the exact order I performed them:

## Experiment 1 - no active zones

I run the command `firewall-cmd --get-active-zones`.

The result is: terminal shows nothing.

## Experiment 2 - add zone=john with no rules

I run these three commands:

```
firewall-cmd --new-zone=john --permanent;
firewall-cmd --reload;
firewall-cmd --get-active-zones;
```

The result is:

The web page renders properly.

But my terminal still does not print any active zones.

## Experiment 3 - add rules to zone=john

I run these three commands:

```
# replace 1.1.1.1 with my home's ip address
firewall-cmd --zone=john --add-source=1.1.1.1/24 --permanent;
firewall-cmd --reload;
firewall-cmd --get-active-zones;
```

The result is:

Port 80 gets blocked and web page now times out and is unreachable

My terminal prints:

```
john
  sources: 1.1.1.1/24
```

## Experiment 4 - delete zone=john

I run these commands:

```
firewall-cmd --delete-zone=john --permanent;
firewall-cmd --reload;
```

The result is:

My web page is able to reload again.

## Experiment 5 - adding interface=eth0 to zone=public

I tried activating my public zone with this command:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-interface=eth0;
firewall-cmd
firewall-cmd --reload;
firewall-cmd --get-active-zones;
```

The result is:

My webpage is still able to load.

My terminal shows:

```
public
  interfaces: eth0
```

## Experiment 6 - re-adding zone=john

I run these commands:

```
firewall-cmd --new-zone=john --permanent;
firewall-cmd --reload;
firewall-cmd --zone=john --add-source=1.1.1.1/24 --permanent;
firewall-cmd --reload;
firewall-cmd --get-active-zones;
```

The result is:

Port 80 gets blocked and web page now times out and is unreachable

My terminal prints:

```
john
  sources: 1.1.1.1/24
public
  interfaces: eth0
```

## Final Result

So after all these experiments, `firewall-cmd --list-all-zones` will show this:

```
block
  target: %%REJECT%%
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:


dmz
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:


drop
  target: DROP
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:


external
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:


home
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client mdns samba-client ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:


internal
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client mdns samba-client ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:


john (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources: 1.1.1.1/24
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:


public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 80/tcp
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:


trusted
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:


work
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

---

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

I rebuilt this VPS machine using Ubuntu 18.04 and ran the exact same script above.  The result is **success**.  I can add a new zone without blocking `port=80/tcp` on `zone=public`.

I rebuilt this VPS machine using CentOS 8.  Then I took the script above and replaced `apt-get` with `yum` or `dnf`.  The result is **success**.  I can add a new zone without blocking `port=80/tcp` on `zone=public`.

I rebuilt this VPS machine again with Ubuntu 20.04 and ran the exact same script.  The result is **failure**.  The new zone is blocking `port=80/tcp` on `zone=public`.

I don't understand why things fail in Ubuntu 20.04 when it succeeds on Ubuntu 18.04 and CentOS 8.

Comment: Have you installed some other firewall frontend on Ubuntu (e.g. ufw)?

Comment: @MichaelHampton ufw came default with Ubuntu20.04. So you can see in my scripts at the beginning of this question I immediately `systemctl stop ufw && systemctl disable ufw`

Comment: @MichaelHampton I updated my question to say issues do not appear in Ubuntu 18.04 or CentOS 8 either. Issues only appear on Ubuntu 20.04.  All experiments conducted on the same machine with clean installations of the linux distro

Answer (score 1):

Check [`AllowZoneDrifting`](https://firewalld.org/2020/01/allowzonedrifting) on all systems:

```
grep AllowZoneDrifting /etc/firewalld/firewalld.conf
```

Setting it to `no` (and running `systemctl reload firewalld`) on **Ubuntu 18.04** and **CentOS 7** systems will yield the same behavior as **Ubuntu 20.04**. As a matter of fact, if you checked the logs on CentOS, you probably will see a message that looks like:

```
firewalld: WARNING: AllowZoneDrifting is enabled. This is considered an insecure configuration option.
```

To solve your problem, once you add `1.1.1.1/24` to your sources list, you can add the `http` service (or port `80/tcp`). For example:

```
firewall-cmd --new-zone=john --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=john --add-source=1.1.1.1/24 --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=john --add-service=http --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

To check you may run:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=john --list-all
```

Answer (score 0):

This confused me for a while, because I thought zones were also filtered based on the services enabled, but the other answer here and [this article](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/understanding-firewalld-multi-zone-configurations) revealed that this is not the case:

> A source (or overlapping sources) cannot be assigned to multiple zones.

In other words, if you define a source IP, *all* traffic from that IP will be captured by that zone, regardless as to whether the relevant service is enabled or not.

In this case, HTTP(S) traffic from `1.1.1.1/24` will *not* fallback to the `public` zone, even if *only* the `ssh` is active on the `john` zone.

You need to define *all* services you want enabled for a zone if you are filtering it by IP.

```
# Make sure the public zone has HTTP(S) access
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=http
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=https

# Remove public SSH access
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --remove-service=ssh

# Add SSH *and* HTTP(S) access for the john zone
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=john --add-service=http
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=john --add-service=https
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=john --add-service=ssh
```